# Picasso for android Main errored

Tags: android, picasso

I used Picasso by the next lines:

```
    ImageView im = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.picassotest);
    Picasso.with(this).setLoggingEnabled(true);
    Picasso.with(this).load("http://lacuadramagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/sangeh-monkey-forest-101.jpg").into(im);
```

but nothing shows when I run the app.
I've added the `INTERNET` permission but still nothing happens.
The only logging lines I got from this is:

```
 12-01 17:28:49.460 7453-7453/? D/Picasso: Main        created         [R0]    Request{http://lacuadramagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/sangeh-monkey-forest-101.jpg}
 12-01 17:28:49.463 7453-7472/? D/Picasso: Dispatcher  enqueued        [R0]+5ms 
 12-01 17:28:49.464 7453-7474/? D/Picasso: Hunter         executing    [R0]+6ms 
 12-01 17:28:49.476 7453-7472/? D/Picasso:    Dispatcher  batched      [R0]+18ms for error
 12-01 17:28:49.479 7453-7453/? D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established  0xb42d6b00, tid 7453
 12-01 17:28:49.701 7453-7472/? D/Picasso:    Dispatcher  delivered    [R0]+243ms 
 12-01 17:28:50.265 7453-7453/? D/Picasso: Main        errored         [R0]+807ms
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is that image too big? Try  a different image and see what happens

Comment: Yes, if that image is bigger thank 2K or 4K not sure, but it won't show up, else make sure your internet connection is stable.

Comment: I just tried it, works fine for me.  On Picasso version 2.5.2

Comment: I've tried it with many kinds of pictures - including thumbnails.

Comment: refer to https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/463

Answer (score 8):

I don't have enought points to put comments.

Do you have tried to use the picasso listener to get the stacktrace?

```
ImageView im = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.picassotest);

Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(this).listener(new Picasso.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();        
    }
}).build();

picasso.with(this).setLoggingEnabled(true);
picasso.with(this).load("http://lacuadramagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/sangeh-monkey-forest-101.jpg").into(im);
```

Comment: You could try to recover the image directly to see if there is a problem:
`
 URL url = new URL("http://lacuadramagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/sangeh-monkey-forest-101.jpg");
 Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
 im.setImageBitmap(bmp);
` 
Oviously don't use this in production code, as it blocks the UI thread. That's only to catch the error.

Comment: run picasso.with(this)... without with(this). you already pointed it when building. otherwise it won't catch exception

Answer (score 1):

This problem is cause because of caching.

Device Setting -> Apps -> Your Application Name -> Clear Cache

Works in my case.